# Android, Espresso, onData(), how find row with boolean column?

Tags: android-espresso

When I want to find row by int column I do smth. like this:

```
@Test
public void testDetailsClickAnyId() {
    onData(withRowInt(MyTable.ID_COLUMN_NAME, 123)).perform(click());
}
```

And it's work.

But I need also to find row by boolean column (not exist method **withRowBoolean()**).

Smth. like this (error example):

```
 @Test
public void testDetailsClickIsView() {
    onData(withRowBoolean(MyTable.IS_VIEW_COLUMN_NAME, true)).perform(click());
}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Did you try withRowInt(MyTable.IS_VIEW_COLUMN_NAME, 1)?

Comment: Yes, it's work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as follows from comments, the answer is to use the next sample of code:

```
onData(withRowInt(MyTable.IS_VIEW_COLUMN_NAME, 1)).perform(click());
```